# Omniauth-Facebook: Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm using a test app with a test user to test Facebook registration/login on my staging environment. I've verified that Heroku has the correct Facebook var values for the app. When initiating a Facebook registration, the callback is returned with the message "Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials"."

Checking the logs, I see the following output:

```
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"Error validating client secret.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

Facebook auth does work locally using test users with a test app. Please let me know if any code snippets are helpful and I'll get them posted.

**Update**
I've verified several times that the App ID and App Secret provided by Facebook are correctly loaded into environment vars on Heroku.

Comment: Probably app secret token you have in your app is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe you. Nothing personal but that's the way it is. Check this answer as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14616284/2422778

Comment: @MichalSzyndel So I most definitely did have the right ID and Secret in place. HOWEVER, I called the variable FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET in my config and FACEBOOK_SECRET on Heroku. So I'll say thanks, since your questioning pushed me to take a look again leading to the real error :)

Comment: @MichalSzyndel If you provide an answer saying to check all those things again I'll make sure to accept it, otherwise I'm going to supply my own answer so others can find the resolution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook exchange code for token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575477/facebook-exchange-code-for-token)

Comment: @justinraczak believe it or not i made the exact same mistake! Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the environment variables contain the correct value for your app id and secret. Make sure the environment variables have the same name in your app config and stored on Heroku.